# How to use .trim() method with this code?

Tags: java, android

When I fetch data from database there are so many spaces come due to not properly format of data. how to use .trim() method with this code.

```
@Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        groupDeals.addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                                           @Override
                                           public void onEvent(@javax.annotation.Nullable DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot, @javax.annotation.Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
                                               if (e != null) {
                                                   return;
                                               }
                                               if (documentSnapshot.exists()) {

                                                   String grpDealsDetails = documentSnapshot.getString(GROUP_DEALS_KEY_DEALS);

                                                   if (TextUtils.isEmpty(grpDealsDetails)) {
                                                       tv_groupDeals.setText("Not Available");
                                                   } else {
                                                       Spanned descripti;

                                                       if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
                                                           descripti = Html.fromHtml(grpDealsDetails, Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY);
                                                       } else {
                                                           descripti = Html.fromHtml(grpDealsDetails);
                                                       }
                                                       tv_groupDeals.setText(descripti);
                                                       tv_groupDeals.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
                                                   }

                                               }
                                           }
                                       }
        );
    }
```

Comment: Please have a look at the /help section here on SO. This is not a site that gives you solutions to your problems, we help with programming issues. So you need to give it a try first yourself. If you have issues with data from the DB why not talk to the people in change of that DB or data.

Answer (score 0):

Before setting `tv_groupDeals.setText(descripti);`
You can add `descripti= descripti.trim();`

Answer (score 0):

you can do this
before setting a value to text in u, do this
tv_groupDeals.setText(descripti.toString().trim());